# setLineDash() not working with jQuery Scrollpath plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

With HTML canvas paths, I'm trying to implement the [jQuery Scrollpath plugin](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) from Joel Besada - which was going well until I tried to see about making the path into a dashed line.

I found documentation online for setLineDash() which looks like you just add it in along with your other 2D context line styles, before calling stroke(), so I altered that section in the jquery.scrollpath.js file and added that in with all my other line style customizations, but no luck.

I've set up a CodePen here with Joel's [demo](http://codepen.io/lightsandswirls/pen/LGPgEp) source code:

The only thing I added was line 391 to the Scrollpath plugin in the js pane:

```
context.setLineDash([50,3]);
```

Any thoughts why it wouldn't work?

Comment: It's working, just make your segments with more space than the `lineWidth` or you won't see it. (it is 10 in your example and the 5 gap is smaller than it) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLBVyx

Comment: ps, it's actually due to the `setLineCap(round)` which will add the strokewidth to the end and start of the path's segment

Answer (score 1):

setLineDash more common mistake is to set the gaps between dashes too short.

When dashing you have to think about the linecap:

[image]

That line part after the grey dash is exactly half the stroke width.

So if you are dashing a line that has a stroke width of 50, a gap of 51 is the minimum to have a gap of 1 white pixel if you are using the strokeCap `'square'` or `'round'`.

If you use `'butt'` as in the firs example, any gap will be visible.

Comment: This is actually really important when using `MKOverlayRenderer` directly. Typically the line width will be set to `MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale)` so,  the array values in the dash pattern should be set to multiples of this, instead of literals..